# What happens to a dying Revenant in the Stunning Palm stance?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, races

> **Unnatural Vitality:** When you drop to 0 hit points or fewer and are subjected to the dying condition, you can choose to be dazed, instead of falling unconscious. You make death saving throws as normal, and if you fail one, you fall unconscious instead of being dazed.

> **Stunning Palm:** Until the stance ends, you cannot be dazed or stunned, and you can use the Stunning Palm Attack power.

> **Stance:** A stance lasts until the character assumes another stance or until the character falls unconscious or dies

What would happen to a Revenant Monk currently in the Stunning Palm stance who is reduced to 0 or fewer HP? Are they unable to choose to be dazed? If they choose the option, are they not dazed?

Answer (score 7):

Wording is important here. I highly suspect that there isn't an official answer to this (other than possibly a WotC CustServ response, to the extent those can be considered official), so this is just my interpretation.

Unnatural Vitality says you can *choose* to be dazed instead of falling unconscious. Stunning Palm says you can't be dazed. If you can't be dazed, then being dazed isn't an option when you're picking between being dazed and falling unconscious. If you can't pick dazed, then you *have* to fall unconscious.

Personally, I would let a player in this situation "change their mind"; that is, s/he could fall unconscious, ending the stance, then say no, I want to be dazed instead now that the stance has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ( not in revenant case ) then you HP are <=0 you are falls unconscious, and any effects on you provided by your powers end.

So IMHO in your case next is happening:

1) Your character stay in the Stunning Palm stance.
So now you cannot be dazed or stunned by any power or effect.

2) Your character recieve damage an his HP stay 0 or lower

a) Your stay is end now and have no effect more, coz you start falling in unconscious

b) Unnatural Vitality - now you can choose take to be dazed **instead** falling in unconscious

In another words answer in Unnatural Vitality. Then you have 0 or lower HP you falls unconscious **anyway** and in this moment you can take be dazed **instead**. So your stay is ends anyway, you only can choose effect(fall unconscious or be dazed) as usual.

Comment: I don't agree with your logic here. Stances end when you fall unconscious, not when you hit 0hp. If something were to knock you unconscious without affecting your hp, you would still lose a stance.

Comment: Of course you lost it. I say abt situation Soulrift ask. Like what happening in every next moment. Then your hp 0 or lower you fall unconscious. If any other effect make you unconscious you also lost stance.